# Regex backreference and Intellij

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij.

I have this xml:

```
...
<ml:comment />
<ml:pohpoh>
...
```

and i want to make it look like this:

```
...
<ml:comment />
<ml:dodo>Volvo</ml:dodo>
<ml:pohpoh>
....
```

but there is a lot of it, so i wanted to use the replace in path feature.

However, this doesn't work (i am trying a single relpace-in-file before I replace all in the path!)

Find:

```
ml:comment />[\n].*<ml:[^dodo]
```

Replace:

```
ml:comment />\$1.*<ml:dodo>Volvo</ml:dodo>\n\$2
```

Also ~ I am concerned the right number of spaces won't be put in, how would i capture all those spaces?

Comment: `[^dodo]` matches a single letter that isn't `d` or `o`. It isn't for matching a string that isn't `dodo`.

Comment: You capture the spaces by putting parentheses around `.*`, and then using `$1` in the replacement. You're already using `$1` and `$2`, but there are no capture groups for them to match, so I can't figure out what you expect it to do.

Comment: So you want to find/replace `(<ml:comment\s*/>)\s*<(?!ml:dodo)` , `$1\n<ml:dodo>Volvo</ml:dodo>\n<` ?

Comment: @sln, based on the question you need to check it's not already followed by a dodo tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Find:**

```
(<ml:comment\s*/>)(\s*)(?!<ml:dodo)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1$2<ml:dodo>Volvo</ml:dodo>$2
```

This should maintain indentation which I assume is what you were worried about in terms of losing whitespace.

[Working example on RegExr](http://regexr.com?379ls)

Answer (score 3):

So you want to find/replace
 `(<ml:comment\s*/>)\s*<(?!ml:dodo)` ,
 `$1\n<ml:dodo>Volvo</ml:dodo>\n<` ?

Comment: +1 for beating me too it. Already had it ready in regxr when I saw yours though so couldn't bare not posting it ;)